# Mapping pojos for lines in CSV file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm new to spring batch, I know that the reader reads a line from a file and assign that to a POJO, but my file has been divided into four categories

1.) Header
2.) Body
3.) Detail
4.) Trailer

And I have four different POJOS as same, can help in suggesting a way to map the content to pojos.

Sample file

H,xxxxxx,yyyyy,12345
B,aaaaaaa,bbbbbb,cccccccc,......
D,dddddddd,fffffff,ggggg,hhhhhh,......
T,ccccc,1

Comment: can you provide a sample of your file?

Comment: Updated in the query

Comment: why don't you use one pojo for all the fields?

Comment: Hi @gaetan that's business requirement as those fields are mapped to different tables in the db

Comment: then you have to create a new csv pojo to read the entire file, don't use the existing ones